# Compare 2 date time column in azure table storage and copy to destination using ADF copy activity only if there is difference

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

I have 2 table storages . I need to copy data  using ADF from Table 1 to Table 2 only if ActualTime == Timestamp. How can I achieve this?
Basically I need to copy rows to Table 2 only if there is no difference in the ActualTime and Timestamp

Table 1

| PartitionKey | RowKey | UpdatedTime | ActualTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1111 | 2022-04-1623:12:19Z | 2022-04-1621:12:19Z |

Table 2

| PartitionKey | RowKey | TimeStamp | UpdatedTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1111 | 2022-04-1623:12:19Z | 2022-04-1621:12:19Z |

Comment: 1) Is it actualTime of table1 == Timestamp of table 2? 
2) Do you want to copy the row to Table2 or else update the table2?

Comment: @Aswin I want to check whether actualTime of table1 == Timestamp of table 2 , if it is true  copy the row to table 2

Comment: What is the primary key? Should we take UpdatedTime=Timestamp for matching partition keys between both tables?

Comment: Yes, Partition key and Row Key combination

Comment: When we combine partition key+Row key  and check , there can be multiple rows in table2? AM I correct?

Comment: If it is partition key+Row key combination then there will be 1 record  for that combination in Table 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253777/discussion-between-aswin-and-jen).

Comment: If there is one record only for that combination , when we copy the row from source to sink, there can be an another row for that combination. So Can you confirm is it to insert a new row or update the existing row?